# HEAD function inside aggregation function SUM

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, mdxstudio

How do I change this script so that `HEAD` is not inside the aggregation function `SUM`?

The reason I'd like to do this is that I'm being warned that:

> Function 'Head' was used inside aggregation function - this disables block computation mode

```
WITH 
  SET [LatestDate] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20060611] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales] AS 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sales_EquivMTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      Head
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Children
       ,11
      )
     ,[Measures].[Sales]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sales]
   ,[Measures].[Sales_EquivMTD]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace

```
Head
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Children
       ,11
      )
```

with a range expression:

```
[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Children.Item(0) : [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Children.Item(10)
```

But I am not sure if that helps performance wise. And it could cause an error on members having less than 11 children.

Comment: @frankPI +1 thanks - wonder why Mosha's tool giving me this message? There must be a valid alternative approach. Maybe since he last updated the tool the engine has been changed so this runs in block mode.

Comment: If you get 2mins spare could you please check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588874/mdx-how-to-calculate-measure-against-dimension-without-displaying-members-in-res/26591528#26591528 . I'm sure you'll know the answer to it but I've attempted and answer and am fascinated to know why it doesn't work ... so if you could comment on my answer I'd be happy!