# MDX How to calculate measure against dimension without displaying members in results

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, adventureworks

Could someone please help me with the below MDX problem:
I got the dataset like the one below:

```
 With
Set Range1 as {[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[1]
:[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[12]}

Set Range2 as 
{[Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[1]:
[Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[12]}

MEMBER measures.A as [Measures].[Internet Order Count] + [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
select {[Measures].[Internet Order Count],A} on columns,
non empty(
[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]*

Range1
*Range2
)
having [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.member_caption
= [Delivery Date].[Calendar].currentmember.member_caption
AND A > 100 
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

The problem is that results are displayed with [Sales Territory] Dimension - I would like to get the results only displaying months but with measure A also calculated against [Sales Territory].

The results for measure A should looks like:

For example: 1128 for January

The Correct results should looks like:
[image]

Thanks

Sorry - was unable to past the code:
[image]

Comment: So you want [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country] to be removed from rows when displaying results since ATM in your query this is using a cross join AND you want the results filtered on [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]?

Comment: +1 great question - fascinated to see the answer. I'm still trying but scratching me head now.

Comment: *** £10 to your PayPal account if you post the answer :) ***

Comment: Actually, as far as I understand the question, you want to get rid of the SalesTerritory. Why do you not just remove or comment out the row after the `NonEmpty(`?

Comment: @FrankPI because I need the measure to be calculated also against [Sales Teritory] - I need to go to the point where I will see the results exactly as in Table2 attached.

Comment: @DanielHanczyc - £10 - you could buy a copy of the answerer's book (Art Tennick). I was just revisiting the question as I was given an answer earlier... I'll add it into my answer anyhow (might even get a +1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[A] AS
   [Measures].[Internet Order Count] + [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Internet Order Count], [Measures].[A] } ON COLUMNS,
 [Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON ROWS
 FROM (
   SELECT { [Measures].[Internet Order Count] } ON COLUMNS,
   Filter (
     Filter ( [Date].[Calendar].[Month] * [Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month], [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name = [Delivery Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name ) * [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country],
     [Measures].[Internet Order Count] + [Measures].[Reseller Order Count] > 100
   ) ON ROWS
   FROM [Adventure Works]
 )
WHERE [Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2008]
```

Comment: +1 for Art Tennick helping: http://www.amazon.com/Practical-MDX-Queries-Microsoft-Analysis/dp/0071713360/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1414621043&sr=1-1&keywords=art+tennick

Answer (score 1):

I've ignored the ranges for now but this is as close as I can get:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.c1 AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER measures.c2 AS 
    [Delivery Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER measures.x AS 
    IIF
    (
      measures.c1 = measures.c2
     ,
      [Measures].[Internet Order Count] + [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
     ,null
    ) 
  SET q AS 
    Filter
    (
        [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]*
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS*
        [Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
     ,
      measures.x > 100
    ) 
SELECT 
  {measures.x} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Extract
    (
      q
     ,[Date].[Calendar]
     ,[Delivery Date].[Calendar]
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

**EDIT**

The following gives two options for the Rows - option A and option B:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.c1 AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER measures.c2 AS 
    [Delivery Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER measures.x AS 
    IIF
    (
      measures.c1 = measures.c2
     ,
      [Measures].[Internet Order Count] + [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
     ,null
    ) 
  SET q AS 
    Filter
    (
        [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]*
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[1]*
        [Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
     ,
      measures.x > 100
    ) 
SELECT 
  {measures.x} ON 0

//<<<<<Option A.try just this and sum the cells ....1128 
 ,q  

//<<<<<Option B.try just this and sum the cells ....1221
//,Extract
//    (
//      q
//     ,[Date].[Calendar]
//     ,[Delivery Date].[Calendar]
//    ) 

ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

**EDIT 2**

This gives the correct answer - be mean of me not to reference the real author: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be750f75-0e39-41b8-9578-9dceb58a5865/strange-context-aware-behaviour-of-adventure-works-script?forum=sqlanalysisservices

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.c1 AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER measures.c2 AS 
    [Delivery Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER measures.[Calendar Month] AS 
    measures.c1 
  MEMBER measures.[Delivery Month] AS 
    measures.c2 
  MEMBER measures.x AS 
    IIF
    (
      measures.c1 = measures.c2
     ,
      [Measures].[Internet Order Count] + [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]
     ,NULL
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    measures.[Calendar Month]
   ,measures.[Delivery Month]
   ,measures.x
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
    {
      NonEmpty
      (
          [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[Country].MEMBERS*
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[1]*
          [Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
       ,measures.x
      )
    }
  - 
    {
      Filter
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
            [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[Country].MEMBERS*
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[1]*
            [Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
         ,measures.x
        )
       ,
        measures.x < 100
      )
    };
```

Comment: whytheq - your suggestion looks very interesting - it execute the condition "[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption  = [Delivery Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption" but for some reason second bit of having "AND A > 100" do not apply on the results...

Comment: @FrankPI any ideas why this query is behaving like this? If I leave out the `extract` function and sum manually then it is the correct answer but hiding the territory dimension seems to make the processor use the All member on that dimension

Comment: whytheq - When applying the ranges - this is still calculating like on any other suggestions posted here - so - its not working...

Comment: @DanielHanczyc I know its not working. 3hrs last night of trying all sorts and this is as close as I've got ....none of us have even got a +1 !! It's a fascinating post - hopefully FrankPI can help.

Comment: @FrankPl thanks for looking - something interesting is definitely going on. You have AdvWks - let me add more to my answer so you know the exact problem as I'm pretty sure you'll be able to answer this one.

Comment: @FrankPI ok - I've added an illustration as a second script. Try the two different options for Rows. Option A adds up to the desired number but when I try to Extract the required dimensions the context changes to the All member of geography, so the total for the month is > 100 and returned. I can see what is happening just not sure how to stop it!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with sales territory, by doing the following instead of your current `from [Adventure Works]`

```
from (
    select {[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]} on columns
    from [Adventure Works]
)
```

Having said that, you can then remove the sales territory from here.. and just have `Range1 * Range2`

```
non empty(
[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country] 
Range1
*Range2
)
```

You can then continue to filter, using the MDX [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx) function

```
from (
    select {[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]} on columns
    from
        ( 
            select { 
                FILTER (
                                         [Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS
                                        ,[Date].[Calendar].currentmember.member_caption = [Delivery Date].[Calendar].currentmember.member_caption and A > 100
                       )
            } on columns
            [Adventure Works]
        )
)
```

Comment: Hi Mez this looks better now - but still do not apply filters correctly: please see my query amended with your suggestions:

Comment: @DanielHanczyc I do not see any updates to your query?

Comment: I posted that as a pic as was getting error when trying to post a code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63710/discussion-between-mez-and-daniel-hanczyc).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see  `[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]` in the final `SELECT`, you can use `EXISTS` clause in MDX

```
 With
Set Range1 as {[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[1]
:[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[12]}

Set Range2 as 
{[Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[1]:
[Delivery Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[12]}

MEMBER measures.A as [Measures].[Internet Order Count] + [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]

select {[Measures].[Internet Order Count],A} on columns,
non empty filter((
exists({Range1
*Range2}, [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]
)), measures.A > 100)
having [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.member_caption
= [Delivery Date].[Calendar].currentmember.member_caption
```

Comment: Hi Souvar_Agasti - your query also do not apply for "AND A > 100" :(

Comment: the results are still the same (wrong) - they should match with the values in the table which I posted on the top of my question.